# VirtualBox Manager needs to be open or a Headless VM goes offline

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, headless

I know this sounds weird but I have a VM with Debian with some services so it doesn't need a GUI.

But after a few minutes running (not immediately) this VM goes offline as if its sleeping or something like that but as soon as I open the VirtualBox Manager without even opening the VM itself this goes online again and as the manager is open it never goes offline again.

This is on a fresh install on Windows 10 and VirtualBox Version 6.1.32 r149290 (Qt5.6.2)

I know that I don't need the VirtualBox manager to be open, I've been using headless VM's for years so this is really frustrating.

Comment: This almost sounds like a bug, and therefor it may be better to post this question on the VirtualBox support forum. If it indeed is a bug, the developers will take notice.

Comment: Maybe check the VM state using `VBoxManage` and/or VNC/RDP access.